# Summarize data frame in r

Tags: r

I need help grouping and summarizing a data frame please.  I've looked through a number of possible answers, but I haven't found anything that quite gets my there.

I have a data frame similar to the following:

```
structure(list(Country = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L), 
                                   .Label = c("CA", "MX", "US"), class = "factor"), 
               var1 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
               var2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), 
          .Names = c("Country", "var1", "var2"), class = "data.frame", 
          row.names = c(NA, -6L))

Country var1 var2
     US    1    1
     MX    1    1
     CA    0    1
     US    1    1
     US    0    1
     MX    1    0
```

I need to summarize the data by country with a couple of stats.  I need a total count of rows for the country and a sum of each var.  For example:

```
Country Frequency Sum.var1 Sum.var2
     US         3        2        3
     MX         2        2        1
     CA         1        0        1
```

Comment: What exactly did you try and did it "not get you there"? Please clarify exactly where you are having trouble. Make this sound more like a question rather than a request for someone to just do it for you.

Comment: Have a look at reshape2, more specifically the family of 'cast' functions: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/reshape2.pdf

Comment: You should post data in a form that can be copied into a console session.

Comment: @BStepp I just added code to replicate your data, please verify that it produces the same data as you had originally.

Comment: Thanks @Barker - yes the code does match what I had.  Sorry if I wasn't specific enough - I didn't want to make the post too long running through everything I'd tried.  In short, I could get the sum by country, but couldn't get the sum and length together in a single data frame without having to create a new frame for the sum, another one for the length/frequency, and then trying to combine them.  I knew there had to be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `dplyr` package

```
df <- df %>% group_by(Country) %>%
    summarise(Frequency=n(), Sum_var1=sum(var1), Sum_var2=sum(var2))
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly and was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The aggregate function can give you the results you are looking for.  I would use the following call:

```
aggregate(df, df["Country"], 
          function(x) ifelse(is.numeric(x), sum(x), length(x)))
```

What it is doing:

1. `df` the first argument is the data you are trying to summarize, so just your initial data frame.
2. `df["Country"]` is specifying the groups you want to use to summarize your data frame, in this case, the country IDs.
3. `function(x) ...` this is defining a custom function that will be applied to each column of `df` using the groups defined by `df["Country"]`.  Here we use an `ifelse()` call so that for the `var` fields (which are numeric), we use a different function than for the `Country` field.  `sum()` which is applied to the `var` fields will sum by country where as `length()` will get the number of occurrences for each country.